# Switching from one Yammer domain to another

Tags: yammer

We have an instance of Yammer on our network, for which access is seamless, via office 365

https://www.yammer.com/domainOLD.co.uk

Following a merger, we would like to switch to a new tenancy, and a new instance of Yammer

https://www.yammer.com/domainNEW.co.uk

Users on domainOLD are required to log in with new email accounts, whereas domainNEW have seamless office 365 access.

**The problem is that anyone who has ever connected to yammer on domainOLD will get redirected to domainOLD whenever they try and connect to domainNEW.**

For Chrome, it is simply necessary to delete any cookie containing 'Yammer'.  For IE10 (and 11) the experience is very inconsistent.  Some users simply need to log out of the old yammer and can log straight into the new.  Others have to delete cookies, others can't log into the new one at all.

*How do you make internet explorer 'forget' the old Yammer and redirect logins to the new instance?*

Answer (score 1):

The answer in most cases is to simply delete cookies, and close / reopen the browser.

In other cases we tried closing *all* browsers, and also Lync, which seemed to work.